# Regex to match a certain string length within an URL

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I need to match a certain url with regex for redirection in IIS URL rewrite.

This is how the url query (and variations) may look:

```
https://example.com/api/GetData/Version/?auth=TTXL9N5XCTCEG3IXF9
https://example.com/api/GetData/Version/?auth=TTXQQ7HWRTCLD3OM67&iid=-1
https://example.com/api/GetData/Version/?t=3&auth=TTXZRKEUROER88HRJ4&iid=-1
```

Now it is important that the auth parameter value has exactly 18 digits (TTX + 15 additional characters) followed by either nothing or something like `&...`.

So I need a regex that is able to recognize the following:

`[Anything before]auth=TTX[exactly 15 additional characters][&... after or nothing]`

My current regex is actually doing well with nothing after the auth, but it is not covering all the variations sadly:

```
(.*)auth=\w{18}$(.*)
```

When I add a character at the end, it does not match anymore.

Maybe somebody can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: `(.*)auth=TTX\w{15}(.*)` ?

Comment: The `$`  anchor matches the end of string. Your `(.*)` does not do much, it always matches an empty string. You need to remove it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, i was wrong with the description actually. corrected it now. Your variation matches also when the auth parameter is longer than 18 characters. But it should not match when it is longer, unless there is another parameter afterwards (which is always a & actually). So in that case, it should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*)auth=\w{18}(?=&|$)` [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3t46m)

- `(.*)auth=\w{18}` looking for ...auth=[a-zA-Z0-9_] (yes _ is included in \w)
- `(?=&|$)` positive lookahead for & or end

**TIP**

Concider using `[A-Z0-9]` instead of `\w` to match your token.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want regex matching only query string key `auth` containing 0-9 and A-Z, use this:

```
(.*)[?&]auth=TTX[A-Z0-9]{15}(&.*)?
```

It matches any url that has auth in query string with value TTX<15characters>, then is only query string item allowed.

---

CertainPerformance posted in comment this solution: `(.*)auth=TTX\w{15}(.*)`. That has a one small problem: it allows auth be longer than TTX+15 characters.

Comment: Actually, your answer allows more than 15 characters, the last part `&?(.*)` makes conditional only the `&` character, if it is not present, everything else will be captured

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira It is fixed now.

Comment: Just tested it in IIS Manager, this still positively matches when there is any character after the end of the auth string (not only &). it is only creating a new group match with an & character though. Check this: https://regex101.com/r/DZrkoE/2

Comment: You have to add `$` to end if you want to match whole string.